# hide / show table row with radio button MVC

Tags: javascript, c#, html, model-view-controller

I have a employee list I pulled it through my database, and I would like to add Radio button to hide / show table row in my list.

I write this in veiw :

```
 
          @*  ---Active part*@ 
            <div class="form-group">
                <div class="row">
                    <div class="col-md-3">
                        <label>Correct Identification</label>
                    </div>
                    <div class="col=md-4">
                        <div class="form-check form-check-inline">
                            @Html.RadioButton("IsCorrectIdentification", 1, new { @class = "form-check-input" })<span>Yes</span>
                            @Html.RadioButton("IsCorrectIdentification", 0, new { @class = "form-check-input" })<span>No</span>
                        </div>
                    </div>
                    <div class="col-md-5">
                        @Html.ValidationMessageFor(model => model.Active, "", new { @class = "text-danger" })
                    </div>
                </div>

            </div>
```

and my controller is :

```
        public ActionResult Active() 
        {
          
            return View();


        }

        [HttpPost]
         public ActionResult Active(Employee Model)
        {
            if (ModelState.IsValid)
            {
                var Employee = db.Employees.Where(x => x.EmID == Model.EmID).SingleOrDefault();
                if (Employee != null)
        }
```

It is a Active table contain : ActiveId(1,2) ActiveNme(yes,no)

my edit page controller code :

```
        public ActionResult EditEm2(int? id) //add the same data type from the viwe page 
        {
            var Result = db.Employees.Where(x => x.EmID == id).SingleOrDefault(); // create "resultreturn a value to edit page 
            ViewBag.DepartmentData = db.Departments.ToList();
            ViewBag.GenderData = db.Genders.ToList();
            ViewBag.NationalityData = db.Nationalities.ToList();
            return View(Result);


        }

        [HttpPost]
        [ValidateAntiForgeryToken]
        public ActionResult EditEm2(Employee Model)
        {
            if (ModelState.IsValid)
            {
                var Employee = db.Employees.Where(x => x.EmID == Model.EmID).SingleOrDefault();
                if (Employee != null)
                {     // item i want to edit in edit page , Em ID must be can not 
                    Employee.EmID = Model.EmID;
                    Employee.EmNameEN = Model.EmNameEN;
                    Employee.EmNameAR = Model.EmNameAR;
                    Employee.NationalityID = Model.NationalityID;
                    Employee.BirthDate = Model.BirthDate;
                    Employee.EmplymentDate = Model.EmplymentDate;
                    Employee.GenderID = Model.GenderID;
                    Employee.DepartmentID = Model.DepartmentID;
                    Employee.ContactPhone = Model.ContactPhone;
                    db.Entry(Employee).State = System.Data.Entity.EntityState.Modified;
                    db.SaveChanges();
                }

                return RedirectToAction("indexEm");

              
            }
            else
            {

                EditEm2(Model.EmID);

            }
            return View();
```

I tried to pull data from the table and create effective code, but I did not understand it

Answer (score -1):

First, create a radio button list in your view:

```
@Html.RadioButtonFor(model => model.IsVisible, true) Yes
@Html.RadioButtonFor(model => model.IsVisible, false) No
```

Next, add a JavaScript function to toggle the visibility of the table row based on the selected radio button value:

```
<script>
  $(document).ready(function () {
      $('input[type="radio"]').change(function () {
          var isVisible = $(this).val() === 'true';
           $('#myTable tr').toggle(isVisible);
      });
  });
</script>
```

In this example, we're using jQuery to listen for changes to the radio button selection and toggle the visibility of the table row accordingly. The var isVisible variable is set to true if the "Yes" radio button is selected, and false otherwise. We then use the toggle() method to show or hide the table row with the ID "myTable".

Finally, in your controller action, you can pass the IsVisible property as a parameter to the view, like this:

```
public IActionResult MyAction()
{
  MyModel model = new MyModel();
  model.IsVisible = true; // Or false, depending on your default state
  return View(model);
}
```

This will pass the IsVisible property to the view, which can then be used to conditionally render the table row.

Comment: no , controller code is not useful , also it must be                                                                                                                                    public ActionResult Active()
{
  Active model = new Active();
            model.ActiveName = yes; // Or false, depending on your default state
            return View(model);
}      but dose not work